# Is there any way to speed up typing a math symbol which has an argument, symbol^(variable)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I wish to type

```
$s^{(L)}$
```

But the `L` symbol is a variable

It could be, `$s^{(1)}$`, `$s^{(2)}$` (basically any integer),  `$s^{(L-1)}$`, `$s^{(L+1)}$`

Typing this is very time consuming. Because I have to type `{ (`, make a decision on which variable to use, then type `) }`.  Is there any way to speed up this process?

I have seen the usage of # character in `\DeclareMathSymbol`. I don't know if this is related.

Comment: Would you always have to type a sequence? Or sometimes just a single term in the sequence?

Comment: @Werner Just a single term. I did not mean to write out a sequence

Comment: This isn't really a LaTeX answer but: Get a better text editor, for example I use TeXstudio which closes brackets automatically so pressing `{` or `(` automatically becomes `{}` or `()` with the cursor between the brackets. Then `s^{(L)}` goes from 7 key strokes to 5, as well as this it allows you to define macros, I have one so `^^` automatically expands to `^{}` with the cursor between the curly brackets. It doesn't save on key strokes but it is faster to push the same button twice than two separate buttons

Comment: it's only 7 characters and realistically you are not going to get lower than 3, so saving 4 characters, there are 400 characters in the question so  you will need to be using this over 100 times before there is a net saving.

Comment: It is not only the question about saving typing. Author (or other people) have to look at the source file and read it (sometimes), so the question is also about comfort when reading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `\s` isn't already defined as a macro, you could define it via

```
\providecommand{\s}[1]{s^{(#1)}}
```

and then write

```
$\s1, \s5, \s P, \s{L-1}$
```

in the body of the document to generate

[image]

Comment: Hmm thank you. Could I ask what [1] and #1 are?

Comment: @AgyptischerMarsch -- The `[1]` part tells LaTeX that the macro `\s` takes `1` argument, and `#1` refers to the first (and only) argument of the macro. If you're more comfortable with encasing single-character arguments of `\s` in curly braces, you could replace `$\s1, \s5, \s P, \s{L-1}$` with `$\s{1}, \s{5}, \s{P}, \s{L-1}$`. I listed the version without explicit curly braces in the answer, as I was under the impression that you wanted to use as few keystrokes as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can set `s` as math-active character:

```
\mathchardef\mathSc=\mathcode`s
\def\mathS{\mathSc \futurelet\next\mathSa}
\def\mathSa{\ifx\next^\expandafter\mathSb\fi}
\def\mathSb^(#1){^{(#1)}}
{\catcode`s=13 \global\let s=\mathS}
\mathcode`s="8000

%test:
$s+s^(2)$  % gives: s + s^{(2)}
```

If you can accept writing `\s` instead of `s^` and `{...}` instead of `(...)` in the source file then the declaration is much more simple:

```
\def\s#1{s^{(#1)}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect it would be this complex

Comment: @AgyptischerMarsch: This version is complex because it’s trying to get a quite unusual syntax — it’s a technically impressive result, but not really practically needed.  The second approach this answer gives, or the version in [Mico’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586431/1635), are much more normal and sensible ways to do it, and show that it isn’t complicated.

Comment: `\protected\def\mathS`?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of variety, here's a completely different approach from the one given in [my earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586431/5001) to achieving the OP's formatting objective. That approach works fine if there is exactly variable -- `s`, say -- that appears in the base of expressions such as `s^{5)}` and `s^{(L-1)}`. It is *not* so fine, though, if you also need to output `r^{5)}` and `t^{(L-1)}` as well, say.

If you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, you can make use of Lua's pattern-matching capabilities to let you input `s!1!`, `p!5!`, and `Q !L-1!` and have it come out as if you'd written `s^{(1)}`, `p^{(5)}`, and `Q^{(L-1)}`.

- Here, `!` takes the role of some delimiter character which doesn't occur frequently in math.
- Of course, `!` is widely (universally?!) used in mathematics to denote factorials. Hence, if your document contains lots of factorial expressions, you'll either have to choose a different delimiter character or write `n{}!` to disrupt the pattern matching routine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- Define a Lua function to do all of the work:
function automate ( u )
   -- Search pattern: alphabetical character, possibly followed by whitespace,
   --    followed by non-empty material delimited by '!' characters.
   return ( u:gsub ( "(%a)%s-!(..-)!" , "%1^{(%2)}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% Assign this function to LuaTeX's 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer", automate , "automate" ) }}
  
\begin{document} 
$s!1! \quad p!5! \quad Q !L! \quad \alpha ! \omega ! \quad 5! \quad n{}!$\quad Hello{}! \quad Hello!!
\end{document}
```